# Unable to Install sql server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I am facing issue at the time of installing sql server 2017 developer edition. I am getting following error :

### 1)   TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Setup

The following error has occurred:

PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2. Command line: C:\WINDOWS\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x590D6427%25400x24BDAA65%25401260%25401

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

### 2)  TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Setup

The following error has occurred:

No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x0F90E2F6%25400xDC80C325

---

BUTTONS:

&Retry

### Cancel

### 3)  TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Setup

The following error has occurred:

The system cannot find the path specified

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%25400xDC80C325

4)

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Setup

The following error has occurred:

The system cannot find the file specified.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x37D77D9E%25400xDC80C325

---

BUTTONS:

&Retry

### Cancel

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue then please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run this [Fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) in your computer.

Remove remnants from previous installations as instructed [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Tips0026.htm).

1. Uninstall all SQL Server components you can using Control Panel -> Programs and Features

   2. Backup the registry.
   3. Delete the following keys in regedit:

   --HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server

   --HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer

   4. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and delete all the sub-keys referencing SQL Server.
   5. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services and delete all the keys referencing SQL Server.
   6. Rename all the SQL Server folders in the computer like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server and subfolders.

Finally  run the [sfc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) tool to repair your operating system. After that, try to install SQL Server 2017 again.

```
sfc /scannow
```